# add custom parameters to imagemagick by patching sources

Tags: c, parameters, imagemagick, patch

i need to modify the behavior of the coder "caption" to fit my needs. Therefore i need to add a new parameter called "maxpointsize" which requires an integervalue.

The source can be downloaded here: [imagemagick 6.7.3-3 source](ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.7.3-3.tar.gz).

There seems to be an easy way to access the parameters, see **coders/caption.c** lines 138 or 141:

```
caption=ConstantString(GetImageProperty(image,"caption"));
gravity=GetImageOption(image_info,"gravity");
```

but i cant put the puzzles together. i have tried this

```
int maxsize = (int) GetImageProperty(image,"maxpointsize");
```

but a make gives me this warning

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

can anyone see, what iam missing?

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

`GetImageProperty` returns a string, typed as `const char *`. You need to convert that string to an integer using your favourite string to integer function, e.g. `strtol`. Your present code will not work since it is merely *casting* rather than *converting*.